# Jenkins android build failing with the message: FATAL: The Gradle wrapper has not been found in these directories

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I try building android project, build fails with the following msg:

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/stable-dev
[Gradle] - Launching build.

FATAL: The Gradle wrapper has not been found in these directories:   
/Users/admin/Downloads/android_stable_dev, 
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/stable-dev

Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Configurations I used:

1. `Use Gradle Wrapper`
2. `build File: /Users/admin/Downloads/android_stable_dev/build.gradle`

I tried filling `/Users/admin/Downloads/android_stable_dev/gradlew`, `/Users/admin/Downloads/android_stable_dev/gradle/wrapper/`, `/Users/admin/Downloads/android_stable_dev/gradle/` etc. in the `Wrapper location` field in the configuration. Still didn't work (All those files are there).

I'm using `jenkins-2.47.pkg`

Comment: firstly try running same command in your terminal  gradlew assembleDebug or what's your task name. if it works for local then their is issue with folder path.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I run build on terminal, it works. No problem there.

Comment: Also, I don't see any problem in the folder path.

Comment: if your cloned file path is correct it will run the command their too. is your jenkin job cloning the code base correctly, you can check this one in workspace folder

Comment: The Jenkins here is not the cloning codebase. I'm just running the build using Jenkins. The codebase is being deployed here by some web hook running on the git server. Also, the Jenkins workspace folder and the android codebase folders are different. And actually if you look  at the error, it says that it could find Gradle wrapper neither in the Jenkins workspace nor in  android codebase folder

Comment: that is what i am mentioning here, you have to go to that Jenkins workspace folder which exist on jenkin server and run the command else it will not run.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I am currently going to the jenkins server and clicking on the `build now` button. What do you mean when you say that you have to go to jenkins erver and run the command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136452/discussion-between-punit-sharma-and-ranjjose).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only have to provide the location of parent folder of the gradlew and build.gradle and not the files. So in your case

```
Root Build script: /Users/admin/Downloads/android_stable_dev
Wrapper Location: /Users/admin/Downloads/android_stable_dev
```

It is mentioned in the help (click ? next to Wrapper Location and Root Build script options) but I too found this out after carefully reading it multiple times

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting the correct file path in Jenkins of your gradle wrapper, you can set this using cd command and run the specific task like below.

```
cd ${WORKSPACE}/Android/YOUR_CODE_FOLDER
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Comment: Where should I do this? In the configuration of the `freestyle project` I have in Jenkins ?

Comment: yes in that section you need to make necessary changes

Answer (score 1):

The problem was as I suspected, the permissions. Once I set the required permissions, things started working.

Comment: Hi. Can you please share the configuration of your job. I am facing same problem

Comment: As I said, the problem didn't have much to do with configuration. The real issue was the folder permissions. My Jenkins is on an OS X machine and hence I had to give read & write access to all the required directories.